# With Anaconda installed, tkinter will only open when run as Administrator

Tags: python, tkinter, anaconda, python-idle

Apologies if this is a very basic issue.

Having programmed in a number of languages I have decided to learn Python. I first installed Python 3.5. Then, in order to manage packages, I installed anaconda which also comes with Python 3.5. When i attempt to open IDLE I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\username>idle
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts\idle-script.py", line 4, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 1544, in main
root = Tk(className="Idle")
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1868, in __init__
self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
{C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\tcl\tcl8.6}
```

The error says it cannot find a usable init.tcl. However, init.tcl is present. I have found other answers on here that advise deleting .idlerc files and/or folders. This did not work.

However, when IDLE is run as administrator it works perfect. So, I checked the environment variable path and noticed that the admin path variables do not contain the anaconda path whereas mine do (It's my work laptop and I am not the administrator). I presume these were included with the default anaconda installation. These Environment variable paths for my user profile are:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3;
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts;
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Library\bin
```

I also found answers on here stating that python does not need to be uninstalled when installing anaconda so i presume its down to the path variables. I realise anaconda comes with Spyder which looks like it has alot more functionality than Idle but just wondering what is causing this issue?

Comment: With IDLE you'll get to some limits very fast. Think about using a more complex IDE such as PyCharm.

Comment: I presume that if you left IDLE out of the picture and tried to use tkinter with Anaconda's python, you would get the same failure.  I believe there has been a question about this before, but I don't remember that there was a satisfactory answer.  If indeed, `import tkinter; root=tkinter.Tk()` fails with Anaconda, you might report that to Continuum Analytics.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Yes, you are correct. tkinter fails for the same reason with Anaconda's python also.